# Unobtrusive client-side validation on multiple fields

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I'd like to validate a model based on the values of multiple fields. My model looks like this:

```
public class CreateStudentEventViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }

    public bool HasTimes { get; set; }
    public bool IsMilestone { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        // some other random test
        if (this.IsMilestone)
        {
            if (this.EndDate != null)
                results.Add(new ValidationResult("Event is a milestone but has an end date selected."));
        }

        if (this.HasTimes)
        {
            if (this.StartTime == null)
                results.Add(new ValidationResult("Event has times, but no start time was selected."));

            if (this.EndTime == null)
                results.Add(new ValidationResult("Event has times, but no end time was selected."));
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

So on the server side, the code in the `Validate()` method will be run.  But how can I translate this somehow to the client side?  Do I have to rewrite this somehow as a custom rule for jQuery validate?

Comment: You need to create you own attribute that inherits from `ValidationAttribute` and implements `IClientValidatable`. [This article](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) might help you get started. But you could also look at [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) which has a number of useful validation attributes that may solve you needs, for example `[RequiredIfTrue("IsMilestone")` applied to the `EndDate` property

Comment: @StephenMuecke your comment, particularly the last part, answers my question excellently - would you consider adding it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) have a number of useful validation attributes which should meet the conditions you have indicated, in particular the `[RequiredIfTrue]` attribute. These will give you both client and server side validation based on the value of another property.

```
public class CreateStudentEventViewModel
{
  [Required]
  public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
  [RequiredIfTrue("IsMilestone")]
  public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
  [RequiredIfTrue("HasTimes")]
  public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
  [RequiredIfTrue("HasTimes")]
  public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }
  public bool HasTimes { get; set; }
  public bool IsMilestone { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to create your own attributes that give client side validation, then you need to inherit from `ValidationAttribute` and implements `IClientValidatable`. Although a little old, this article [THE COMPLETE GUIDE TO VALIDATION IN ASP.NET MVC 3](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) is a good reference.